# Programmatically copy class files from within a jar to another jar

Tags: java, jar

I have an application as jar file (that includes a bunch of classes.)

Within the running of the application I want to create a new Jar file as an output.

I can do this no problem if I get the individual classes from the current jar as a resource, write them to disk as respective classes, then when I create the new jar file read them all in and create the new JAR.

However, I don't think this is smart nor efficient... and that I'm probably overlooking something really obvious...

I'm hoping I can simply copy the resource over in memory without writing the files out again that I need.

Today I do this:

```
File[] list = new File {
    new File("Class1.class");
    new File("Class2.class");

Manifest m = new Manifest();
m.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
m.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS, main_class);
JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fout), manifest);
for(int n=0;n<list.length;n++) {
    add(list,target)
}
target.close();
```

The Function add is per below:

```
private static void add(File source, JarOutputStream target) throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try {
        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            int count = in.read(buffer);
            if(count == -1)
                break;
            target.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        target.closeEntry();
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
```

Now this all works fine... but it relies on the fact that I'm reading the relevant class files from the disk. What I want to do is read the relevant class files from a resource jar file... AND THEN write the class files I want back out to a completely new jar file.

Ideally what I want to do is this:

Within the main application:

```
InputStream[] stream = new InputStream[] {
    MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("Class1.class"),
    MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("Class2.class")};
```

Then take that stream and write that back out into a new Jar file.

So making the add function above now be an add(InputStream, JarOutputStream target).

Am I on the right track or is this making a mountain out of a mole hill?

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: *Why* do you want to create a jar out of files that already exist in the current one?

Comment: I think this is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Extract the files is easy, it's just a zip file.  Appending them to another Jar file is more difficult.  You will need to create a completely new copy of the destination jar, adding the new files before you close it, delete the existing jar and rename the new copy back into its place

Comment: This may be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/copy-a-file-from-one-zip-to-another

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's pretty much what I want to do. I'm trying to do this without writing the unzipped resource to the filesystem. I only want to write the new Jar. So, unless there is another way, I want my "add" function above to take an InputStream array of the resources.

Comment: @chrylis one possible output of the application is to generate a new jar file for other purposes. This new jar file uses a number of the classes from its parent. So I simply want to copy from the parent Jar the classes I want and make the new jar.

Comment: @Ramjet That's the problem, you can't "add" to a zipfile.  You will need to open the existing zipfile and copy it's contents to a new zipfile, when done, and before closing it, you will need to add the new entries.  When done, close the new zip file, delete the old one and rename it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll accept that as an answer then Mad. i.e. The method is to open the existing JAR - copy what you need to a new jar, and clean up accordingly.